# How to create an array Expression?

Tags: c#, expression

I have a mongoDB collection which I would like to filter by creating a expression based upon parameters.

```
string desiredExpress = @"x['columnName'].ToString() == value";
```

The system.linq.expressions namespace does have an arrayAccess expression but this is limited to type int32 which prevents the reference by column name.

Update including code snippet. The following code produces the expression x => x == x:

```
private static Expression<Func<BsonDocument, bool>> BuildPredicate(JArray valueNames, string row, string[] colNames)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BsonDocument), "s");

        List<Tuple<string, string>> parameters = valueNames
            .Select(vn => Tuple.Create(vn[TARGET].ToString(), row.Split(',')[GetFieldIndex(new Field { name = vn[TARGET].ToString() }, colNames)])).ToList();

        foreach(var parameter in parameters)
        {
            Expression e = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(parameter.Item2), Expression.Constant(parameter.Item2));
            predicate = predicate == null ? e : Expression.AndAlso(predicate, e);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<BsonDocument, bool>>(predicate, argParam);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you want one of the `Expression.Property` overloads that returns `IndexExpression`.

Comment: A general `IndexExpression` seems to be what you want. [Expression.ArrayAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.arrayaccess) is just a factory method for specific case of index expression, general index expressions can be created using [Expression.MakeIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.makeindex) or one of [Expression.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.property) overloads.

Comment: Thanks again @JonSkeet Mr Skeet! I quite enjoy your publications!